# How to show that the integral $\int_{0}^ {\infty} \frac{x^n}{(1+x)^m}dx$ converge when $m > n+1$ when $m,n$ are both positive integers?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How to show that the integral $\int_{0}^ {\infty} \frac{x^n}{(1+x)^m}dx$ converge when $m > n+1$ when $m,n$ are both positive integers?

I have tested this for specific numbers and it looks like we need to use partial fraction decomposition. Is there some general formula for that we can use here?

Comment: In which way is this question connected to [tag:multivariable-calculus]?

Comment: It is much easier to show it converges than to compute it.  Near $x=0$ compare to $\int x^n$ and near $+\infty$ compare to $\int x^{n-m}$.

Comment: Hint: the integrand is asymptotic to $x^n$ ($x^{n-m}$) for small (large) $x$.

Comment: It is evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110457/815585)

Comment: @FShrike i actually made a typo which is edited now. but it looks similar enough to what you linked...

Comment: Oh. For that, apply some variable substitutions to arrive at the Beta function, as done on the Wikipedia page

Comment: $x=t/(1-t)$ works I think.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the integral $\int^{\infty} x^{-p} dx$ is finite if $p>1$. So here the given integral is asymptotically $J\sim \int^{\infty} x ^{-(m-n)} dx$ and it will be convergent if $m-n>1$.